# Meaning of a phrase in David Ricardo's literature

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

In the preface of Ricardo's *On the Principles of Political Economy and Taxation*, a sentence reads:

> To supply this deficiency, abilities are required of a far superior cast to any possessed by the writers of the following pages.

I understand the sentence is saying that a greater ability is required by the writer to fill up the deficiency. What I don't understand is the grammar and the usage of "cast" and "possessed". What is possessed, "abilities" or "cast"? And this "to" as a preposition feels awkward.

Answer (score 6):

So I think there are a couple of things that might be throwing you off, and let's try to tackle them one by one.

First, let's get the quote right. Properly quoted, the original line goes like this:

> To supply this deficiency, abilities are required of a far superior cast to any possessed by the **writer** of the following pages

The original has **writer**, not "writers". This is significant because you appear to have failed to realize the author is talking about himself here. **He is "the writer" in this line**.

The word "cast" is a noun here with a slightly dated/formal-sounding meaning.

> characteristic quality ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast))
> his father's conservative cast of mind

> the character of something. (Google/Lexico)
> "this question is for minds of a more philosophical cast than mine"

"a far superior cast to any possessed by the writer" is referring to better character than what the writer Richardo himself has. He is being modest. Basically he is saying, in order to bridge a gap left by other writers, a writer needs stronger qualities and abilities than those that he possesses, but he still thinks he deserves a shot. That's why he goes on to say this:

> yet, after having given to this subject his best consideration—after the aid which he has derived from the works of the above-mentioned eminent writers—and after the valuable experience which a few late years, abounding in facts, have yielded to the present generation—it will not, he trusts, be deemed presumptuous in him to state his opinions on the laws of profits and wages, and on the operation of taxes.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this text is from 1817; the language and tone is somewhat outdated.

1. "Cast" is using the definition found [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast) in the noun list, 10b, a "characteristic quality."
2. "to" is idiomatically paired with "superior." We would say that one thing is "better *than* another," but "superior *to*" it.
3. The language can be a bit better understood by rearranging and paraphrasing it: "To make up for this deficiency, one would need abilities of a type far superior to any that the writers of the following pages possess."